# Using inputType on a TextView in a list item layout

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem, listactivity

I've made a ListActivity.  I have an xml file that defines the layout for this Activity.  I also have an xml file that defines the layout for an item in that list.  This item layout has 3 TextViews inside of it.  If I add the inputType="text" property to one of these TextViews, the onListItemClick handler no longer executes when I run my application in the emulator.

I noticed that singleLine="true" was deprecated, which is why I switched it out for inputType="text".  Does anyone know why this is happening?

Note: I'm developing against 2.1

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Setting an inputType probably causes the TextView to be focusable , and when you have a focusable element in a ListView row, the row is no longer clickable.

InputType has to do with users entering text.  The equivalent to singleLine="true" would be lines="1", not inputType="text"

Comment: Thank you, I understand now :D  It threw me off because when I type :singleLine inside TextView XML I get a tooltip telling me to use inputType

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had resolved this issue by making textview's property focusable, false.

android:focusable="false"

Hope this would be useful to someone, as singleLine property is deprecated and inputType text is preferred.