# inputType makes item un-clickable

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `ListView` in which each item has a complex layout that contains, at some point, a `TextView` with `android:inputType="text"` and `android:ellipsize="marquee"`. My problem is that `inputType="text"` does *something* that renders the whole listview item un-clickable. I've tried:

- `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the top-most layout of an item,
- `android:focusable="false"` on the `TextView` itself,
- `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` on the `TextView` itself,
- `android:clickable="false"` on the `TextView` itself,
- `android:editable="false"` on the `TextView` itself.

Nothing worked.

The reason why I use `android:inputType="text"` on a `TextView` is so that it becomes single-line and `android:ellipsize="marquee"` actually works. I've done my homework:

- `android:singleLine` is deprecated*
- `android:lines="1"`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354589/using-inputtype-on-a-textview-in-a-list-item-layout), doesn't work, the text still wraps, you just don't get to see the second line, so the marquee effect does not appear.

---

* or is it? My Ctrl+Space in Eclipse says this about `android:singleLine` (emphasis mine):

> Constrains the text to a single horizontally scrolling line instead of 
>    letting it wrap onto multiple lines, and advances focus instead of 
>    inserting a newline when you press the enter key. * **Deprecated**: 
>    This attribute is deprecated and is replaced by the textMultiLine 
>    flag in the inputType attribute. Use caution when altering 
>    existing layouts, as the default value of singeLine is false (multi-
>    line mode), but if you specify any value for inputType, the default 
>    is single-line mode. (If both singleLine and inputType attributes 
>    are found, the inputType flags will override the value of 
>    singleLine.). [boolean]

However, [the docs](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine) do not say anything about any deprecation.

What's going on here?

Comment: I have the exact same issue...  fallback is to use the deprecated android:singleline, but would love to see how to accomplish this without using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually in [the official documentation of R.attr](http://d.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine) that attribute constant **is** deprecated.

However (as mentioned) this is contradicting [the TextView documentation page](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3asingleLine). And when looking at the related methods, setting the singleLine attribute is equivalent to :

```
myTextView.setTransformationMethod(new SingleLineTransformationMethod());
```

which too isn't deprecated. And it is how i dance around that deprecation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your needs, however if I do here is the code I used for list item (it has image on the left and text on the right, the text is limited with 2 lines and uses ellipsize feature):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/list_item_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10px" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_label"
        android:textSize="16sp" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:ellipsize="marquee" 
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you need 1 line limit probably try to use `android:maxLines="1"`?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, the marquee effect is not visible (just like with `lines="1"`. Also, `inputType="textMultiLine"` makes the whole item unclickable, just like `inputType="text"`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as [the official, online documentation](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3asingleLine) does not mention that `singleLine` is deprecated, I will not consider it so. It must be a bug in the SDK. I will use `singleLine` for as long as it is not marked as deprecated in the documentation and until there's a fully working, non-deprecated alternative.